# Selects that are focused have black font text color in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design, dark-mode

There aren't many drop down selects in general but they're used in https://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs

When the select is focused, the option values and the selected value font color switches to black.

[image]

Is this working as intended?

*firefox 77.0.1 OSX*

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? Looks like an OSX scroll bar - are you using OSX's built in dark mode?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I did have OSX dark mode actiavted. After switching it back to light mode, I am still getting the black text on the selects when focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed - Firefox did have a bug with rendering the select option text. Thank you for reporting this.